# Swift: Run a specific code when app is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have a framework that returns a ViewController to my app upon request. 
This view controller contains a QR code that is subjected to change after a certain period of time - say 3 days.

I would like to call a method contained inside the framework after 3 days so that the changed/updated QR is readily available even if the user is not using the app actively. When user opens the app - the updated QR is there!

For that, I have used below in my ViewController inside the framework - (from [tutorial link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time))

```
//MARK:- Add Timer to run QR Logic after 5 seconds
            let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(5)

            let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(QrUIViewController.performQrFetchLogic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

This piece of code works perfectly when app is active/background. Is it possible, and how to achieve this even if the app is killed?

PS: I read Jobscheduler and AlarmManager will work for Android - is there something similar to these in iOS?

Comment: In iOS you can run application code in the background for some specific reasons (like location updating, voip, etc. see here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started).

Comment: It is really bad for the device energy conservation to fire up a timer every 5 seconds for an event that will occur only in 3 days.  When creating the Date object, you can specify the interval from now.          let threeDaysInterval: TimeInterval = (3600*24)*3
        let threeDaysFromNow = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: threeDaysInterval)
        let timer = Timer(fireAt: threeDaysFromNow, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateQrCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Comment: @ekscrypto - that is just a sample.  I will be doing it after 3 days and once my updated QR is received, I am invalidating the timer.

Comment: How to make it work when app is killed

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is probably using a scheduled [Local Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1).

You schedule local notification for some time in the future and then afterwards react to it. This is the case both for when the app is active, in background or inactive.

Remember that notifications do not fire if the user kills your app.

Comment: You don't. Apple specifically considers _users killing your app_ to be a sign they've somehow reached a state where the app is inoperable and thus untrustworthy. iOS immediately revokes any background priviliges from such apps. Note that this isn't the same as iOS killing your app. If iOS kills your app normally, background tasks are still permitted.

Comment: that's a good catch! clear for me...
and, could be a silly question - kill app and terminate app are one and the same - is that correct?

Comment: The words are used interchangeably. So yes, mostly correct. It's annoying that we don't know the word Apple uses off-hand. That would make it clearer.

Comment: Local Notifications are supported from ios10+.
my app supports ios8+ :-(

Comment: You're thinking of the UserNotification framework. That is iOS 10 and higher. There's also UILocalNotificiations that are from a very old version of iOS. You can support both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154988/discussion-between-spacyricochet-and-lohith-korupolu).